# How do I keep open the console?

Tags: c++, c, console

I tried this:

```
main() {
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: `std::cin.get();`

Comment: There's a newline in the buffer before you call `ignore`.

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: @chris and how do I clean the buffer?

Comment: @Cabezota, You did with `ignore`. After that, `get` will wait for the buffer to have something in it so it can read it.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on `return 0;`!

Comment: How are you launching the program?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify your source in order to do this. This tends to be annoying when you exit the program from other places with exit() or abort(). Most IDEs have an option to keep the console open. Are you using Dev-C++ by any chance? It has an option to pause the console. You can find that option in the environment settings. Unless you're using the outdated version of Dev-C++ from Bloodshed. If so, you should update to the Orwell version: http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to simply place:

```
system("PAUSE");
```

wherever you want the pause to be (in your case, in the line above return 0;)

However due to lots of security issues, most would consider the use of `system` to be bad practice.  Instead, try using:

```
cin.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a fan of using:

```
std::cout << "Paused. Press Enter to continue.";
std::cout.flush();
std::cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
```